# MPI_Send/Recv not transmitting initial entries

Tags: fortran, mpi

#### Problem

I'm building a simple MPI Send/Recv hello world in Fortran and am running into an odd error.  I want to make sure I'm not missing anything trivial before blaming OpenMPI or gfortran.

In the code below I send a simple array between two MPI processes.  The first few entries of the data aren't sent correctly.  The tail is fine.

```
Sent      1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
Received  0   0  32   0   5   6   7   8
```

I expect `sent` to equal `received` and it does so after the first few entries.

#### Environment

These results come from `gfortran-4.6.3` and `openmpi-1.6.4`.  A colleague ran this using `ifort 13.0.1` and obtained correct results.

#### Code

```
program main
    implicit none
    include 'mpif.h'

    integer rank, size, ierr

    call MPI_INIT( ierr )
    call MPI_COMM_RANK( MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierr )
    call MPI_COMM_SIZE( MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, ierr )
    ! print *, 'Process ', rank, ' of ', size, ' is alive' 

    if (rank .eq. 0) then
        call sender()
    end if
    if (rank .eq. 1) then
        call recver()
    end if
    call MPI_FINALIZE( ierr )
end program

subroutine sender()
    implicit none
    include 'mpif.h'

    integer i, ierr
    integer dat(8)
    do i=1, 8
        dat(i) = i
    enddo
    call MPI_SEND( dat, 8, MPI_INTEGER, 1, 2001, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr )
    print *, "Sent     ", dat

end subroutine

subroutine recver()
    implicit none
    include 'mpif.h'

    integer i, ierr
    integer stat
    integer dat(8)

    dat = -1
    print *, "Empty    ", dat
    call MPI_RECV( dat, 8, MPI_INTEGER, 0, 2001, MPI_COMM_WORLD, stat, ierr )
    print *, "Received ", dat

end subroutine
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to have the wrong declaration for stat. It must be declared as an array of size MPI_STATUS_SIZE.

integer stat(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)

Comment: That fixes it for me.

Comment: I've run into this same problem before too. You can use ``MPI_STATUS_IGNORE`` if you're not concerned about the status.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a mismatch between your `dat` integer's size and `MPI_INTEGER`. I would be explicit about both declaring `dat` with an size specification (4 bytes or 8 bytes) ***and*** which MPI data type you are using. E.g. something like:

```
...
integer(kind=4) dat(8) 
...
call MPI_RECV( dat, 8, MPI_INTEGER4, 0, 2001, MPI_COMM_WORLD, stat, ierr )
...
```

or `kind=8` and `MPI_INTEGER8` if you need 64-bit types.

I couldn't reproduce your error exactly as written because Fortran `integer` and `MPI_INTEGER` are the same size on my architecture, but by explicitly mismatching them, I was able to get spurious content at the ***end*** of the received data.

I suspect that you have similar issue on your architecture.

Comment: I am able to reproduce the error, and this doesn't fix it.  kind=4 seems to be the default, while kind=8 results in a clear size mismatch, with the back half of the result buffer filled with the value -1 from the initialization.

Comment: OK, that's what I saw too. Does the status array fix above work for you?